# retrieve domain for a googleplay app

Tags: windows-10, bluestacks, internet-filter

i have techloq installed on my windows 10 pro.

i use bluestacks to run android apps.

Techloq, by default, blocks bluestacks, googleplay, and all android apps that need to connect to a domain.

better said, Techloq blocks all domains that are needed to run bluestacks, googleplay, and googleplay apps.

although bluestacks is officially unsupported, Techloq does allow bluestacks with one or two apps.

customers requesting more than 2 apps in bluestacks are curtuously rejected with the statement, "We are sorry, Techloq does not support Android devices".

When i called customer services the representative explained that the time it takes for technicians to retrieve the URLs (they call them SLLs, anyone care to explain the difference?) that need to be excluded is not cost effective for Techloq.

On the other hand, if i were to attach those URL's along with my submission then they would be happy to oblige.

Does anybody know how to retrieve the URL(s) associated with a given app in googleplay?